# how to dual boot Windows 7 & Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I want to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my PC, but I think I need a little help since this is the first time I do any dual booting. I'm following the instructions from http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

My Computer Specs:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Intel Pentium Dual Core 2.00Ghz
- 320GB HDD (200GB Free)
- 4GB RAM

Which version of Ubuntu should I download? will it really work?
any other help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The guide you use, is outdated. I'd suggest to follow the official [installation manual](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support) instead.

Another Remark: Check first if your mainboard uses UEFI or BIOS. If it uses UEFI, then you have to make sure that you install both, Windows and Ubuntu using the same firmware interface (meaning: both in UEFI mode, or both in BIOS emulation mode). Also, in this case, use the 64bit Version of Ubuntu, since the 32bit one [will **not** dual boot](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), except if you use BIOS emulation for both, Windows and Ubutnu. If you run into troubles, read the Ubuntu [UEFI Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

Answer (score 0):

Steps mentioned in the link you have mentioned are good enough ..

As far as the choice of Ubuntu version is concerned:

I have Ubuntu Raring Ringtail 13.04 x64 on dual boot system with Windows 7 Home Premium x64 and I am quite happy with it ..

But I would recommend 12.04 32-bit for you simply because it is more easy to use and it can run more applications with much much less hastle .. plus it is the recommended version :)

Comment: Why is a 32 bit version easirer to handle than a 64 bit version?

Comment: The 32bit version will **not** work for Dual Boot on UEFI, except if you install Windows using BIOS emulation... You **must** use Ubuntu 64bit to dual boot on UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, that is latest stable version.

If you don't have UEFI, just execute WUBI and it will do your work.

If you have UEFI, burn iso into your USB drive and boot it.

When you successfully entered it, follow the instructions.